# Subset according to a row comparison in the same column

Tags: r

I would like to only select Persons who have "nothing" in the EVENT column after the last "RFA"

Input:

```
structure(list(Person = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), Date = c("13/04/13", "14/05/14", 
"14/05/14", "15/02/15", "13/04/13", "14/05/14", "14/08/14", "14/09/14", 
"14/08/15", "15/10/12", "15/10/14", "15/10/12", "04/03/13", "05/03/13", 
"06/03/13", "07/03/13"), EVENT = c("RFA", "RFA", "RFA", "nothing", 
"RFA", "EMR", "nothing", "RFA", "nothing", "nothing", "nothing", 
"EMR", "RFA", "RFA", "RFA", "nothing")), .Names = c("Person", 
"Date", "EVENT"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L
))
```

Output:

```
Person  Date    EVENT
1   13/04/13    RFA
1   14/05/14    RFA
1   14/05/14    RFA
1   15/02/15    nothing
2   13/04/13    RFA
2   14/05/14    EMR
2   14/08/14    nothing
2   14/09/14    RFA
2   14/08/15    nothing
5   04/03/13    RFA
5   05/03/13    RFA
5   06/03/13    RFA
5   07/03/13    nothing
```

what I have tried:

```
library(dplyr)
PostAblation<-Therap %>% 
  arrange(Person, as.Date(Therap$Date, '%d/%m/%y')) %>% 
  group_by(Person) %>% 
  filter(last(EVENT == "nothing") & EVENT == "RFA")
```

but I don't get the result I expect

Comment: `df %>% filter(EVENT == "nothing" & lag(EVENT == "RFA"))`? something like this?

Comment: But that would return true for every situation when "nothing" followed RFA whereas I want to follow the last RFA

Comment: What do you mean by last RFA? can you paste your desired output?

Comment: The output is in the question

Comment: So if some person has `... EMR nothing` or `... RFA nothing nothing` as the last rows, it has to be deleted?

Comment: No if EMR nothing it will be deleted. If RFA nothing nothing it remains as there is only nothing after the last RFA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your logic is a little bit complicated. But possibly something like this:

```
df %>% group_by(Person) %>% filter(EVENT[max(which(EVENT == "RFA")) + 1] == "nothing")

Source: local data frame [13 x 3]
Groups: Person [3]

   Person     Date   EVENT
    (int)    (chr)   (chr)
1       1 13/04/13     RFA
2       1 14/05/14     RFA
3       1 14/05/14     RFA
4       1 15/02/15 nothing
5       2 13/04/13     RFA
6       2 14/05/14     EMR
7       2 14/08/14 nothing
8       2 14/09/14     RFA
9       2 14/08/15 nothing
10      5 04/03/13     RFA
11      5 05/03/13     RFA
12      5 06/03/13     RFA
13      5 07/03/13 nothing
```

Which says the last `RFA` is followed by `nothing`, assuming your data has been ordered by `Person` and `Date`. A modified version would be:

```
df %>% group_by(Person) %>% filter(max(which(EVENT == "nothing")) > max(which(EVENT == "RFA")) & 
       length(which(EVENT == "RFA")) != 0)
```

Which is less greedy than the first logic, it will be true as long as the person has both `nothing` and `RFA` and there is `nothing` after the last `RFA`.

Comment: This will also have the warning message. Since for some person the event doesn't have `RFA`. But since it is returning `-Inf` and we are trying to find the maximum index, it can be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the data on `Person` and look within that to find the maximum index of "RFA" entries.  Then, add 1 to that index and check if the entry corresponding to the next `EVENT` is "nothing". If so, you keep it:

```
splitPerson <- split(d, d$Person)

afterNothing <- lapply(splitPerson, function(ii) max(which(ii$EVENT == "RFA")) + 1)

keepers <- which(mapply(function(x, y) x[["EVENT"]][y] == "nothing", splitPerson, afterNothing))


d[d[["Person"]] %in% keepers, ]
#   Person     Date   EVENT
#1       1 13/04/13     RFA
#2       1 14/05/14     RFA
#3       1 14/05/14     RFA
#4       1 15/02/15 nothing
#5       2 13/04/13     RFA
#6       2 14/05/14     EMR
#7       2 14/08/14 nothing
#8       2 14/09/14     RFA
#9       2 14/08/15 nothing
#13      5 04/03/13     RFA
#14      5 05/03/13     RFA
#15      5 06/03/13     RFA
#16      5 07/03/13 nothing
```

Comment: I get the warning "In max(which(ii$EVENT == "nothing")) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf" from the b4nothing<- line

Comment: OK on the keepers line I get the error Error in which(mapply(function(x, y) x[["EVENT"]][y] == "RFA", splitPerson,  : 
  argument to 'which' is not logical.......The output from the b4nothing line is a row of numbers for each Person is that correct?

Comment: Ah, it works for me without adding `== TRUE` on R 3.3.0.  You can adjust to `which(mapply(function(x, y) x[["EVENT"]][y] == "nothing", splitPerson, afterNothing) == TRUE)`

Comment: I get nothing returned with the last line d[d[["Person"]] %in% keepers, ]. But keepers has data and so does d. I see that the Person data seems to be in the row.names column in keepers. Do I need to convert it to a data frame?

Comment: @SebastianZeki That is weird.  `keepers` is a named integer vector.  The names are the same as the entries in this case.  This is the `dput`: `structure(c(1L, 2L, 5L), .Names = c("1", "2", "5"))`.  Is that not the case for you?  You could try `d[d[["Person"]] %in% names(keepers), ]`

Comment: so the str for keepers I have is 'data.frame': 339 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ which.mapply.function.x..y..x...EVENT....y......nothing...splitPerson..: int  2 4 8 12 14 15 17 19 21 24 ... The row.names actually has the Person id so I then put row.names as a new column called Person and rename the which.mapply.function to x.  the str for  Person column is then chr. For the other dataframe d the str for Person is also chr so I am also confused

Answer (score 1):

Another option is with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, if(any(EVENT == "RFA") & all(EVENT[tail(which(EVENT == "RFA"), 
                1)+1]=="nothing")) .SD , Person]
#    Person     Date   EVENT
#1:      1 13/04/13     RFA
#2:      1 14/05/14     RFA
#3:      1 14/05/14     RFA
#4:      1 15/02/15 nothing
#5:      2 13/04/13     RFA
#6:      2 14/05/14     EMR
#7:      2 14/08/14 nothing
#8:      2 14/09/14     RFA
#9:      2 14/08/15 nothing
#10:     5 04/03/13     RFA
#11:     5 05/03/13     RFA
#12:     5 06/03/13     RFA
#13:     5 07/03/13 nothing
```